# Iterating through double collections in Java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, iterator, hashtable

I'm a Java beginner, so please bare with possibly silly or trivial questions. 
I have two collections (array lists or hashtables) and I want to compare each and every element of the first collection to each and every element of the second collection. 
I wrote the following code, but this only compares element 1 of the first collection to element 1 of the second collection, element 2 of the first collection with element 2 of the second collection, etc., so I am missing most of the comparisons that I want to make. Can you please help me out?

```
public class IteratorDemo_1 {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Create two array lists:
    ArrayList alLetters = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList alNumbers = new ArrayList();

    // Add elements to the array lists:
    alLetters.add("C");
    alLetters.add("B");
    alLetters.add("Z");
    alLetters.add("X");
    alNumbers.add("1");
    alNumbers.add("6");
    alNumbers.add("3");
    alNumbers.add("7");

    // Use iterator to display the contents of 'al':
    System.out.println("Original contents of 'alLetters': ");
    Iterator itrL = alLetters.iterator();  
    System.out.println("Original contents of 'alNumbers': ");
    Iterator itrN = alNumbers.iterator();  
    while(itrL.hasNext()){  
        while(itrN.hasNext()){
            Object elementL = itrL.next();  
            Object elementN = itrN.next();
            boolean result = elementL.equals(elementN);
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println(elementL + " ");
            System.out.println(elementN + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

}
```

Comment: why `while(itrN.hasNext()){`? what do you expect that to do?

Comment: use a for each inside a for each. First for will loop through your first arraylist and the second for for your second arraylist

Comment: Rahul, although for each works in this specific case, if the OP wants to remove items from the list during the comparison, for each will fail.

Comment: Do you want to compare the 2 lists ? What do you intend to do with the boolean variable result ?

Comment: After comparing each and every elements of the two lists, I want to remove from list 1 those elements that appear in list 2 as well. Can I do this with "for each"?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(itrL.hasNext()){  
    Object elementL = itrL.next(); 
    while(itrN.hasNext()){
        Object elementN = itrN.next();
        boolean result = elementL.equals(elementN);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(elementL + " ");
        System.out.println(elementN + " ");
    }
    itrN = alNumbers.iterator();
}
```

Comment: Can I do exactly the same thing with a hashtable in place of an array?

Comment: A hashtable has keys and values. table.get(key) returns one of the values. Do you want to iterate over the values in it? Just making sure I understand what you want to do.

Comment: I wanted to iterate over the values in two hashtables, compare them, and remove those values in table 1 that appear also in table 2. I've solved this as follows:

Comment: while(itrGar.hasNext()){
    strGar = (String) itrGar.next();
    while(itrNoGar.hasNext()){
    String str1 = garList.getProperty(strGar);
    strNoGar = (String) itrNoGar.next();  
    String str2 = noGarList.getProperty(strNoGar);
    boolean result = str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2);
    System.out.println(result);
    if(result != true){
       } else {
        Object garList_new = garList.remove(strGar);
        System.out.println("Removed element: " + garList_new); 
        System.out.println();
       }
        }
        itrNoGar = noGars.iterator();
   }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
while(itrL.hasNext()){  
    Object elementL = itrL.next(); 
    Iterator itrN = alNumbers.iterator(); 
    while(itrN.hasNext()){
        Object elementN = itrN.next();
        boolean result = elementL.equals(elementN);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(elementL + " ");
        System.out.println(elementN + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it didn't work. :( It compared the first item in alLetters to each item in alNumbers, but did not look at the other items in alLetters.

Comment: You have to get a new iterator for itrN after each completion of the inner loop .

Comment: This issue in the original code appeared to be that the inner loop was pulling off "next() of the L iter repeatedly... 

Mike is correct. I will update my code.